# When is seemingly unrelated regression equivalent to a confirmatory factor analysis/structural equation model?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

[One way](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/multivariate-outcomes.html) of describing a seemingly unrelated regression model  is: $y_n \sim \beta x_n  + \epsilon_j$ where $\epsilon_n \sim MultivariateNormal(0, \Sigma)$. We could rewrite this $y_n \sim MVN(\beta x_n, \Sigma)$.

When $x$ captures outcome-specific intercepts (no covariates), this looks an awful lot like a confirmatory factor analysis. When we further allow $x$ to include other observed predictors whose parameters are assumed constant across items, we seem to have a structural-equation-style-model (SEM) with a latent, reflective outcome measured by multiple variables regressed on those observed predictors. One way the SEM might differ is in the assumptions about the predictor covariances, but I'm not sure.

When is seemingly unrelated regression the same as CFA or the SEM described above?

Comment: The SUR description you link to just looks like a multivariate general(ized) linear model.  I'd point out that X is observed in SUR, but latent in CFA.  A similar comparison is that SUR is a special case of path analysis in which all predictors are exogenous (X) and no outcomes (Y) predict other outcomes.